# Control.Invoke not invoking

Tags: c#, task

Code below is from a dev proof that I'm currently working on:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

...

QueueProcessor = new Task(() =>
        {
            while (processorrunning)
            {
                if (processorrunning && dq.Count != 0)
                {
                    boxid = string.Empty;

                    if (dq.TryDequeue(out boxid))
                    {
                        if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
                        {
                            textBox1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                            {
                                if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty)
                                    textBox1.Text = boxid;
                                else
                                    textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine + boxid;
                                textBox1.Refresh();
                            }));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty)
                                textBox1.Text = boxid;
                            else
                                textBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine + boxid;
                            textBox1.Refresh();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Exception removing boxid from queue.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    trigger.WaitOne(600000, false);
                }
            }
        });
```

All of the if conditions return true. There is a valid boxid string assigned to boxid from the dq.TryDequeue call. Everything except the invoke code works as it should. The code never takes the else on the InvokeRequired test.

Form1.textBox1 never sees a thing. Ideas welcome.

Comment: Have you tried using `Invoke()`, rather than `textBox1.Invoke()` ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak: Tried that at your suggestion and it made no difference.

Comment: Is your task even bein started ?

Comment: The code will never enter the `else` branch because (as far as I can see) the loop runs on a background thread. Hence `Control.InvokeRequired` called on that thread will always be `true`.

Comment: @Zohir: Yes. I've stepped through it several times.

Comment: This `textBox1.Text = boxid;` assigns en empty string so this `if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty)` will always be true, so the else never hits

Comment: @Zohir: (dq.TryDequeue(out boxid)) populates boxid with a valid value.

Comment: Since i don't have the full code, i removed that line, and i assigned a string right when `(dq.TryDequeue(out boxid))` happens and the textboxBox get populated, i also commented out this line `trigger.WaitOne(600000, false);`

Comment: This was a design mistake in .NET 1.0, they gave the least likely to be correct method the shortest name.  Control.Invoke() is very troublesome due to its high likelihood to cause deadlock, a problem that BeginInvoke() does not suffer from.  You must only ever use it when you need its return value, in itself wrong 98% of the time due to the high likelihood of creating a threading race bug.  It is otherwise easy to debug, use the Debug > Windows > Threads debugger window.  Shows you what the main thread is doing.  Usually something unwise, like waiting for the thread to complete.

Comment: @Hans: Thanks! I'll keep that in mind. You'd think they'd have updated the docs by now... ;)

Comment: It is documented, but it just doesn't mean anything to anybody that hasn't yet discovered the need for the Debug > Windows > Threads debugger window to diagnose deadlock.  Threading is hard to get right, use it sparingly and strongly avoid inventing your own code when the BackgroundWorker and Task classes and await/async keywords can do the job for you.